# Selenium Webdriver is unable to connect to chromedriver unless $DEBUG=true in Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, watir-webdriver

I am using Watir webdriver to launch Chrome with the following:

`Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, desired_capabilities: WatirConfig.CHROME_PROFILE, :switches => %w[--disable-cache --ignore-certificate-errors])`

This successfully launches the browser only when `$DEBUG = true`. However, if I set $DEBUG to false, I get the following error:

`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515`

For reference, this is the chrome profile:

```
`preferences = {
        'download.directory_upgrade' => true,
        'download.prompt_for_download' => false,
        'download.default_directory' => download_directory,
        'enable_do_not_track' => true
    }
    @CHROME_PROFILE = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome('chromeOptions' => {'prefs' => preferences})`
```

Any ideas on why I need to be in debug mode to launch the browser?

More Info:
Running on Mac Sierra 10.12.3
Selenium-Webdriver: 3.0.5
Watir-Webdriver: 0.9.9
Chromedriver: 2.28
Chrome: 57.0.2987.98 (64-bit)